# Найти ошибку в коде, добавление в существующий массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

буду благодарен за помощь в решении не большой задачи и чтоб кто-то объяснил что я делаю не так .

Дана задача :
 Нужно сохранить объект в модель, перед этим проверив нет ли в модели уже такого объекта с таким ID.
 Если нет , то просто добавить в модель.
Если есть , то взять из нового объекта который мы хотим добавить в модель,  массив "Получатели" и добавить людей из этого массива в существующий в модели объект, а именно его массив "Получатели", но добавить нужно только только тех людей которых ещё нет в массиве, то есть уникальных, чтоб нельзя было добавить одного получателя 2 раза.

моё решение задачи :

```
//Модель
let rows = [];

//Добавим объект в модель для тестирования 
rows.push(
   {
     'Отправитель' : {
         id: "00000001",
         name: "Андрей"
      },
     'Получатели' : [
         {
             id: "00000002",
             name: "Анна"
         },
         {
             id: "00000003",
             name: "Иван"
         },
         {
             id: "00000004",
             name: "Сергей"
         }
      ]
    }
);

//Объект который мы хотим добавить в модель.Но он уже к примеру есть в модели.
let newObj = {
    'Отправитель' : {
        id: "00000001",
        name: "Андрей"
    },
    'Получатели' : [
        {
             id: "00000003",
             name: "Иван"
        },
        {
             id: "00000005",
             name: "Светлана"
        },
        {
             id: "00000004",
             name: "Сергей"
        },
        {
             id: "00000006",
             name: "Татьяна"
        }
    ]
};

//мой код, проверю есть ли в масиве уже объект с таким ID,
//если есть добавлю получателей в существующий обьект.

if ( rows.some((obj)=> obj['Отправитель'].id === newObj['Отправитель'].id) ){
   //Сначала найду нужный мне обьект в модели, в модели.
   let exist = rows.find((v)=> v['Отправитель'].id === newObj['Отправитель'].id);
   console.log('exist ::: ',exist);

   //набор уникальных получателей которых нет в существующем объекте внутри масива exist['Получатели'].
   let unique = [];

   exist['Получатели'].forEach(function (prev){
       newObj['Получатели'].forEach(function (curr){
           if ( curr.id !== prev.id ){
               if ( !unique.some((v)=>v.id === curr.id) ){
                   unique.push(curr);
               }
           }
       });
   });
   console.log('unique::: ',unique);
   Array.prototype.push.apply(exist['Получатели'],unique);

}else{
    //Если обьекта с таким ID нет в модели и он действительно новый
    rows.push(newObj);
}
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
rows = [
   {
       'Отправитель' : {
            id: "00000001",
            name: "Андрей"
        },
        'Получатели' : [
             {
                 id: "00000002",
                 name: "Анна"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000003",
                 name: "Иван"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000004",
                 name: "Сергей"
             },
             {
                  id: "00000005",
                  name: "Светлана"
              },
              {
                  id: "00000006",
                  name: "Татьяна"
              }
        ]
    }
];
```

Результат который получаю

```
rows = [
   {
       'Отправитель' : {
            id: "00000001",
            name: "Андрей"
        },
        'Получатели' : [
             {
                 id: "00000002",
                 name: "Анна"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000003",
                 name: "Иван"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000004",
                 name: "Сергей"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000003",
                 name: "Иван"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000005",
                 name: "Светлана"
             },
             {
                 id: "00000004",
                 name: "Сергей"
             },
             {
                  id: "00000006",
                  name: "Татьяна"
             }
        ]
    }
];
```

Сортировка не обязательна, просто нужно чтоб массив содержал только уникальных получателей , чтоб их ID не повторялись.
Предполагаю чтоб проверить все возможные дубли мне надо итерировать 2 объекта паралельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function compare(exist, add) {
  return exist.map(el => { // Вернем новый массив
    if (el.Отправитель.id === add.Отправитель.id) { // Отправитель совпал
      add.Получатели.forEach(ad => { // перебериаем получателей
        if (!el.Получатели.find(p => p.id === ad.id)) { // Если не найден, добаляем
          el.Получатели.push(ad); // Добавляем получателя
        }
      })
    }
    return el; // Возвращаем результат
  })
}
```

Функция принимает массив и объект. Пробегает по массиву текущих данных и добавляет новых получателей.

Полный код:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ElemType
 * @property {string} id
 * @property {string} name
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ModelType
 * @property {ElemType} Отправитель
 * @property {ElemType[]} Получатели
 */

//Модель
let rows = [];

//Добавим объект в модель для тестирования
rows.push(
  {
    'Отправитель': {
      id: "00000001",
      name: "Андрей"
    },
    'Получатели': [
      {
        id: "00000002",
        name: "Анна"
      },
      {
        id: "00000003",
        name: "Иван"
      },
      {
        id: "00000004",
        name: "Сергей"
      }
    ]
  }
);

//Объект который мы хотим добавить в модель.Но он уже к примеру есть в модели.
let newObj = {
  'Отправитель': {
    id: "00000001",
    name: "Андрей"
  },
  'Получатели': [
    {
      id: "00000003",
      name: "Иван"
    },
    {
      id: "00000005",
      name: "Светлана"
    },
    {
      id: "00000004",
      name: "Сергей"
    },
    {
      id: "00000006",
      name: "Татьяна"
    }
  ]
};

/**
 * @param {ModelType[]} exist
 * @param {ModelType} add
 * @return {ModelType[]}
 */
function compare(exist, add) {
  return exist.map(el => { // Вернем новый массив
    if (el.Отправитель.id === add.Отправитель.id) { // Отправитель совпал
      add.Получатели.forEach(ad => { // перебериаем получателей
        if (!el.Получатели.find(p => p.id === ad.id)) { // Если не найден, добаляем
          el.Получатели.push(ad); // Добавляем получателя
        }
      })
    }
    return el; // Возвращаем результат
  })
}
console.log(compare(rows, newObj));
```